# Using MySQL triggers to update customers balance

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need some help in understanding triggers and how they work. I have 3 tables:

> **Customers**
>   Id  |  Balance
>
> **Invoices**
>   Id  |  Custid  |  Amount
>
> **Payments**
>   Id  |  CustId  |  Amount

I have an insert statement to insert the invoices:

```
$this->db->insert('invoices', array(
            'CustomerId' => $data['customerId'],
            'Description' => $data['Description'],
            'DateCreated' => $data['DateCreated'],
            'Amount' => $data['Amount']
        ));
```

and need to update the customers balance after the insert. Similarly, after inserting or creating a payment. I need to deduct from the clients balance.

```
public function createPayment($data) {
        $this->db->insert('payments', array(
            'CustomerId' => $data['customerid'],
            'DateCreated' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            'Amount' => $data['amount']
        ));
    }
```

Any assistance would be appreciated in creating these triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need two triggers - one for the invoice table:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER add_invoice_to_balance AFTER INSERT ON invoices
FOR EACH
ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Customers SET balance = balance + NEW.Amount
      WHERE Customers.id = NEW.custid;
END;
//
delimiter;
```

And one for the payment table:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER add_payment_to_balance AFTER INSERT ON payments
FOR EACH
ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Customers SET balance = balance - NEW.Amount
      WHERE Customers.id = NEW.custid;
END;
//
delimiter ;
```

[fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4c3a/1)

Comment: Thank you.. that worked. Much appreciated. Is the NEW.Amount coming from the insert query?

Comment: correct.  If it was an after UPDATE trigger, you would have access to the `NEW` values, as well as the `OLD` values. If this has done the job, feel free to mark it as accepted